# Change order of columns in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I wanted to know how we can change the order of columns in QtableView by dragging ? I currently have a class derived from FilterProxyModel as source to QtableView. I am using QT 4.8

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Qt 5.x:

```
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
```

[QHeaderView::setSectionsMovable()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qheaderview.html#setSectionsMovable)

Qt 4.x:

```
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setMovable(true);
```

[QHeaderView::setMovable()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setMovable)

Comment: Seems like this is not available in Qt 4.8 which I am using

Comment: For Qt 4.8 it should be
[QHeaderView::setMovable ( bool movable )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setMovable)

Comment: Updated answer with 4.8 version